# Adding multipath to server and change lvm to use new devices

Tags: lvm, multipath

I have a server running RHEL5 (HP Proliant DL365) connected to a EVA. LVM is used for the SAN disks like this

/dev/sdav         VolGroup09 lvm2 a-   150.00G   90.00G
  /dev/sdbi         VolGroup08 lvm2 a-   150.00G       0

I want to setup Proliant support Pack and configure the Device Mapper Multipath Enablement Kit from HP.

How do i get LVM to use the /dev/mapper/* disks instead on /dev/sd* disks?

Answer (score 2):

Install RHEL with "linux mpath" option. Otherwise, you can follow the following: http://thomasvogt.wordpress.com/2007/11/29/linux-san-multipathing/

Start with one disk at a time.

It will be easier to reinstall the OS.